# Chrome App - Dynamic Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a Chrome App that displays slideshow/dashboard on the screen. Right now all of the website files (html and .js) are stored in the app. So when the application starts, it can be used completely offline because all of the files it needs are stored internally.

**I'm looking for a way to host the dashboard's files (.js files) on a web server, that the app will query, pull down, and cache fresh copies of at startup.** This will make it easier to update the dashboard but still allow it to be (mostly) offline.

I have been able to have the app query the server successfully and pull down the Javascript files as strings. Normally, I would just inject the JavaScript into the page but that's not allowed with Chrome Apps. My question is, how can I take the JavaScript (pulled down from the server) and load it in the page?

Comment: Something like this? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices

Comment: I don't think so. Isn't this for building a service hosted in Google's Cloud? I'm talking about a Chrome App, that you would download from the Chrome App Store.

Comment: I _think_ this is what I'm looking for: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/sandbox

If I sandbox the page, I should be able to evaluate all the javascript I want

Comment: ^^ but is that something you *really* want to do?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!

If you end up doing it, please at least pull the info to eval from a secure source (e.g. https)

Comment: @CristianCavalli Yes this is something that I want to do and I feel others want to as well. I want my application to be able to work offline but still be able to pull and update its content as well.

And since I'm pulling from my own (https) server I'm not worried about unsafe javascript.